# SQL Agent -- Mail Error 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-agent

So I have recently configured an entire lab environment with the following servers:

Domain: mytekkilab.com

Server 1: DC-08-01
Server 2: SQL-03-01
Server 3: MAIL-08-01
Server 4: TS-08-01
Server 5: WS-08-01

My terminal server (TS-08-01) has Microsoft Office installed with outlook configured on user sqlagent@mytekkilab.com. Sends and receives e-mail fine from the exchange server (2007 SP3 -- MAIL-08-01). The problem lies within the SQL Agent Database Mail. When configuring the profile and the account using sqlagent. I try to send a test e-mail and get the following line wihtin my mail log of the sql server:

> 04/21/2011 11:22:05,,Error,23,The mail
>   could not be sent to the recipients
>   because of the mail server failure.
>   (Sending Mail using Account 2
>   (2011-04-21T11:22:05). Exception
>   Message: Cannot send mails to mail
>   server. (Mailbox unavailable. The
>   server response was: 5.7.1 Client does
>   not have permissions to send as this
>   sender). ),256,10,,4/21/2011 11:22:05
>   AM,sa

I have been researching for the last 2.5 hours and cannot seem to find a solution to this issue. If you can please let me know when you think. Again smtp works for this user everywhere. OWA, Outlook, command smtp etc...

Thanks for your help in advance!
-Mike D

Comment: This is probably a better fit for serverfault.com

Comment: I'd hazzard a guess that you need to check the service configuration to determine the actual user account under which the service runs. It's probably not the same as the logged in user under which you've configured Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, and I suspect the problem is with [the mail relay](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1005384-146-1.aspx#bm1005500).

and

["How to troubleshoot mail relay issues in Exchange Server 2003 and in Exchange 2000 Server"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895853)